# Failed to import bridging header while archiving an IOS app

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, archive

My Xcode project is able to successfully build and run on a simulator but when I try to archive it an issue comes up saying that the project cannot import the bridging header.

Here is the image app working on a simulator.

[image]

Now when I try to archive it onto the generic IOS device I get these errors:

This is the error I get - Failed to import bridging header.

[image] 
Some of the things we tried include:

Moving the files that are not found from the pods folder to the app folder (get errors with duplicate files - even after we delete the files from the pod folder).

Adding the SDK paths to the Release search path (so its not just in the debug path) - we get the same original error.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: pls post the error  message .it will be plus

Comment: error: failed to import bridging header '/Users/Kumar/Documents/Casa/CasaiOS/CasaBridgingHeader.h'

Comment: is it correct path of your bridgingHeader @Pranav

Comment: Yeah - it manages to build and run too. The issue occurs when I try to archive the project.

Comment: ok do one thing remove the bridingheader and add it again to your project ,make sure to click copy items and to your target .

Comment: it is said that Braintreecore.h is not find in you project. please check this file is available or not?

Comment: Kishore - I tried that and still get the same issue. Badal - The file is in the project, it is able to compile and run when I build it. The problem with finding the header and braintree files only occurs when I try to archive the project.

Comment: I have the same issue. It builds and run with no issues but when I try to archive the project it doesn't find the files to import that are listed in the bridging header. As an additional piece of information: 
1. I moved the bridging header at the same level of the .xcodeproj file 
2. I changed the path of the files to import in the bridging header (because now the bridging header is in a different path)
3. Archived the project
---> Now it finds the file imported in the bridging header but since that file imports other files that are at different paths, those files are not found now

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled on this since I had same issue. Here's how I solved it if anybody still interested

Go to your project's settings, "General" tab, scroll down to "Linked Frameworks and Libraries" click "plus" and add all the libraries it fails to import when archiving